# Uninstall software via the registry

Tags: c#, windows, registry, uninstallation

I know this has been asked before, but bear with me.  I have a utility that reads the Unistall location in the registry and then compares the results to a list of applications that need to be removed.  80% of the time this works, but the trick is that one of the items to be removed is the anti-virus (so it can be replaced with an AVG install).  For a lot of the companies this doesn't work.  Here is a snippet of how I'm getting the installed software:

```
const string Win32Loc = @"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall";
//const string Win32Loc = @"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Installer\USerData\S-1-5-18";     
    const string Win64Loc = @"Software\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall";

    List<Application> apps = new List<Application>();
    string location = bool64BitOs ? Win64Loc : Win32Loc;

    using (RegistryKey rk = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(location))
    {
        foreach (string skName in rk.GetSubKeyNames())
        {
            using (RegistryKey sk = rk.OpenSubKey(skName))
            {
                apps.Add(new Application { DisplayName = sk.GetValue("DisplayName") == null ? "" : (string)sk.GetValue("DisplayName"), AppKey = skName });
            }
        }
    }
```

The results look like this when written to a text file:

---

Name PowerDVD Key InstallShield_{6811CAA0-BF12-11D4-9EA1-0050BAE317E1}

Name ESC Home Page Plugin Key InstallShield_{E738A392-F690-4A9D-808E-7BAF80E0B398}

Name Intuit SiteBuilder Key Intuit SiteBuilder

Name Microsoft Visual J# 2.0 Redistributable Package Key Microsoft Visual J# 2.0 Redistributable Package

Name Norton AntiVirus Key NAV

Name Windows Live Essentials Key WinLiveSuite

Name Microsoft Visual C++ 2008 ATL Update kb973924 - x86 9.0.30729.4148 Key {002D9D5E-29BA-3E6D-9BC4-3D7D6DBC735C

---

So you'll see that SOME installs have the key and some don't.  What this means is that the 80% that work have the key for the MSIEXEC call, and the others fail.  I'm playing with the Installer/UserData/UserXXXXX/Products but I don't get how to traverse for all users.  In the dump I provided, Norton needs to go, but I can't see how to do it.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Right. You can't rely on this information being accurate. There's no requirement that installers include the information in the registry. Particularly bad-behaved applications (and Norton is the poster child for these) will not work properly with your 'brute-force' method of uninstallation. The reason you can't find the answer to this question is because there isn't one.

Comment: Good luck removing Norton (programatically or otherwise!). It's the cancer of shop-bought pre-built PCs!

Comment: If you know it has been asked before, why do you ask again? Couldn't you use one of the previous answers?

Comment: It is worth remembering that many application use NSIS to install also, not MSI. You would need to read the location of their uninstaller executable, which NSIS is usually pretty good about putting into the registry.

Comment: A few things:

1) You should likely enumerate both Win32Loc and Win64 Loc registry keys on 64-bit OS.  32-bit apps can be installed on 64-bit os, but can put their uinstall registry key in the non-Wow64 registry.  (Depends on if the original installer had a manifest and/or registry redirection disabled).

2) For the non-MSI installs, the command line to uninstall is the "UninstallString" registry key value. Why aren't you using that to kick off the uninstall?

Comment: I'm using the key found with the MSIEXEC all to ensure the removal is silent to the users.  Thanks for the tips on the 32/64 bit reg entries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree with selbie's comment about using the "UninstallString" instead (although sometimes you won't have that either, but for MSI's use can just get the GUID and use `msiexec /x {GUID}`).

Nevertheless, I would not recommend uninstalling Norton A/V products via this method. Because their uninstallers are crap and frequently leave behind many pieces of the software that should've been removed, Symantec provides a tool that actually gets the job done safely: the [Norton Removal Tool](http://us.norton.com/support/kb/web_view.jsp?wv_type=public_web&docurl=20080710133834EN&ln=en_US). Highly recommended!

Comment: That's perfect for this terrible Norton issue.  Thanks.  for the other uninstallation issues, I'll have to figure that out again.